# How to connect to hard drive that is connected to router?

Tags: router

I have a computer that I am using for work that is running Ubuntu. I need to transfer files constantly between Ubuntu and Windows. What I have been doing is saving the files on a USB stick drive, and then plug that stick drive to the Windows machine many times a day.

I replaced my router with the one that has USB, and bought an external hard drive so I can transfer files more easily. I set it up in Windows, but have no clue how to do it on Ubuntu.

Would you be able to do a step by step in how to do this? I got the router IP address already.

Comment: What type is your router? What is the router's ip address and what is the share name you've given to HDD in your router settings?

Answer (score 1):

Your windows and Ubuntu 12.04 should already be able to transfer files between each other over the network using samba/windows shares.

In the file browsers search your Browse Network/Network Places and see if you can find each of the computers. If not you can type the IP address into the location such as \192.168... or on Ubuntu type smb:///192.168..... (might have to press ctrl-L to show the location bos to type into in the Ubuntu file browser)

As for your router, without more info about what it can do... can't really help but it is possible that the router is able to setup samba/windows shares. This might be what you have done with the "set it up on windows".

Hope this point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have a windows 7 computer at home and my laptop is kubuntu 13.04.

In my windows, i changed the settings of one of my hard drives to be shared with other computers. I had to add my kubuntu computer's name as a allowed computer to my share on the hard drive on my windows 7 computer.

If you have more security than an open share folder at your home, then this will not work. I haven't been able to use the homegroup feature just yet.